# I Call SmartContract Token ERC20, Why Show Hashing Output ? (Web3 + Metamask + Javascript)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, javascript, ethereumjs

I do not know why with this, even though in the previous version (web3 + Metamask) can issue real data. But now used as hashing (output). I took the example in the code and output below (to get the TotalSupply on the ERC20 Token):

```
const contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
const total_supply = contractInstance.totalSupply.getData();
console.log(total_supply);
```

> Output : 0x18160ddd (this is my problem)

How to showing real data? In a sense it doesn't come out hashing. Thanks

Comment: In case my answer solved your problem please mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In web3.js v0.x:**

The expression `contractInstance.totalSupply.getData()` would get you the encoded ABI data (byte-code) of a call to function `totalSupply`.

In order to actually call the function and retrieve the return-value asynchronously, you should use:

```
contractInstance.totalSupply.call().then(total_supply => {
    console.log(total_supply);
});
```

---

**In web3.js v1.x:**

The expression `contractInstance.methods.totalSupply().encodeABI()` would get you the encoded ABI data (byte-code) of a call to function `totalSupply`.

In order to actually call the function and retrieve the return-value asynchronously, you should use:

```
contractInstance.methods.totalSupply().call().then(total_supply => {
    console.log(total_supply);
});
```

Comment: oh version web3. Ok I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The output you receive is in hex format. You need to conver hex to an int.

Here is the full code you need to use:

```
const contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
const total_supply = parseInt(contractInstance.totalSupply.getData());
console.log(total_supply);
```

I added `parseInt()` to convert your hex number into a human readable int.

Comment: I think that `contractInstance.totalSupply.getData()` gives the function selector, not the total-supply. I think that `await contractInstance.totalSupply.call()` gives the total supply (web3.js v0.x). So `parseInt` is the wrong kind of remedy here.